# Can you use document.execCommand('copy') on the contents of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I copy an html table manually, I can paste it into a Google Doc with the formatting preserved (it looks like a table).

How can I copy the contents programmatically, with a button, and paste as an html table? Something like the following...

```
evar copydeck = $("<div>").html(htmlToInsert);
$('body').append(copydeck);
copydeck.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
copydeck.remove();
```

The above code does not work...but this does:

```
copydeck = $("<textarea>").val(this.list.join("\r\n"));
$('body').append(copydeck);
copydeck.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
copydeck.remove();
```

I guess it is because the element must be selectable - like an input or htmlarea field. But they can't hold html (or it is just plain text, not html).

Any way to copy and paste HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes!

```js
   function copy() {
      var target = document.getElementById('my-div');
      var range, select;
      if (document.createRange) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(target)
        select = window.getSelection();
        select.removeAllRanges();
        select.addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');
        select.removeAllRanges();
      } else {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(target);
        range.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
      }
    }
```

```html
  <div id="my-div" style="border:1px dashed #999; color:#666; background:#EEE; padding:2px 5px; margin:10px 0;">
    Hello stackoverflow!))
  </div>
  <div>
    <input onclick="copy()" type="button" value="Copy">
  </div>
```

Comment: @11treesWriting Welcome!;)

Comment: After hours of searching I finally found this solution! I will edit your answer a bit though so that only the text gets copied instead of a selected area.