# How to copy the content into the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, copy

I know how to copy the value of the input, as shown below, but when I try to do the same in a paragraph - for example, it doesn't work, let me know how to solve it?

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    $(this).focus().select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  });

  $('p').click(function() {
    $(this).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' readonly value='click to copy me'>

<p>This is a pararaph</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: It does work when you double click on the p element.

Comment: no i didnot duplicate this

Comment: now i realized that it works by dbl click :D 
two letters to copy better than nothing :D
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use document.execCommand('copy') on the contents of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687696/can-you-use-document-execcommandcopy-on-the-contents-of-a-div)

Comment: what does "Possible duplicate of..." mean?

Comment: It means a very similar question has been asked before and we've provided a link to a possible answer.  Based on the user's reputation, the question may be closed immediately (eg if Rory did it) or you get a vote-to-close option.  If enough people agree that this question is the same as the linked question, then this one is closed as a duplicate.

Comment: oh it's been for days since i am on this website, seems i mistakenly asked that question, so do i have to delete my question ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script to solve that issue:
http://id0t.x10.mx/dl/clipboard.js

Take a look at the script's source for a tutorial on how to use it.

A feature that I added was the true parameter on all the functions. This parameter specifies if the tooltip should be displayed.

Ex.

```
<button onclick="select_all_and_copy(document.querySelector('span'),true)">Click to copy the span!</button>

<span>Here's some text.</span>
```